# why does outlook mail access with imap php giving error everytime?

Tags: php, outlook, imap

---

I have done all the required setting .imap setup is done in outlook mail.imap and less secure app are enabled in gmail a/c

```
//this is my code using to get connected with outlook             
$hostname = '{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';

$inbox   = imap_open("{$hostname}", $user , $pass )   or  die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

if($inbox)
{
    echo'yes';
}
else
{
    echo'No';
}
```

---

Comment: Can you add value of `imap_last_error()` in your post please or add `var_dump(imap_errors())` in `else`.

Comment: getting this-can't connect: Can not authenticate to IMAP server: AUTHENTICATE failed. Account is blocked. Login to your account via a web browser